# Graduated sites show "sketchy" offline page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, design, offline

The Area 51 sites that have graduated (WebApps, Webmasters, Gaming, Cooking, etc.) show `Stack Exchange Beta` on their [offline page](http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm?return=https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions) as seen below.  Shouldn't the name and logo from their graduated design be used instead of the sketchy design?

[image]

Comment: I'd like to upvote but there's no freehand circles... :-(

Comment: @TheUnhandledException, better?

Comment: The SO Dev Team's oy! counter just shot up. I wonder why...

Comment: @rchern *Much better!* Thanks. **+1!**

Comment: -1. Your MS Paint handwriting is too nice.

Comment: Rebecca, @Jon has a point. Are you using a tablet, or what?

Comment: @PopularDemand, no.  A mouse, with my right hand.  And I'm left-handed.

Comment: This issue is still outstanding...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Graduated (themed) sites now have a pretty/matching offline page [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) put in the styling for all these last weekend and I hooked them up this morning.

The exception to this is askubuntu, which will work after the next push.

Keep in mind the error pages are cached for a while, so you may need to hard refresh or clear your cache to see the updated version that redirects to your site's specific offline page (this is necessary due to the load balancer, not one of our IIS servers hosting the page).

Answer (score 13):

As shown in the top of the screen capture, the issue is not so much the image of the page, it's the *url the user is redirected to* that is wrong. Just a helpful hint for the team :-)

**EDIT:** I added a freehand frowny-face, freehand "oy!"s and, for good measure, a freehand crying unicorn...

**EDIT2:** I added smileys of all denominations. Oy, you guys, *Oy Vey!*

[image: Oy! Oy Vey! Oy My Gosh!]

Comment: I'd like to upvote, but you forgot the sad smiley and an oy. (;

Comment: Are you trying to start a new meta meme @rchern? ;-)

Comment: -1, heretically oriented smiley

Comment: @radp: I have added more smileys for you

Comment: Gotta have strong nasal muscles to utter an "oy!" like in the top corner there. ♪

Comment: @TheUnhandledException, I don't try, I just seem to fall into them.

Comment: @Grace Note: That smiley has my family's long Jewish heritage and can utter very, very nasal "oy"s!

Comment: -1 unicorns don't cry. For crying out loud, they crap rainbows!

Comment: Unicorn tears have healing powers... oh wait, phoenix had that, not unicorns.

Comment: `oy oy oy`? Shouldn't that be "Oi! Oi! Oi!"?

Comment: @Andrew **-1**, heretically spelled [Oy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/70807#70807).