# Display onebox title in starred/pinned messages list

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, chat-stars

When a message containing a onebox is starred or pinned, the star list displays the original URL in a hyperlink.

[image: Onebox being turned into an ugly URL]

Instead of a URL, the text should be a descriptive label depending on what kind of onebox it was, when possible.

For example:

- Stack Exchange posts: "Q: [Title]" or "A: [Title]"
- Chat rooms: The room name
- Amazon, YouTube, xkcd, etc: The title/name of whatever being linked to, perhaps?

Comment: Is it required to draw the smiley(frowney?) as if it's an emoticon even when freehanding? Does typeset text now constrain us in every medium?!

Comment: YES, DO WANT!!!! Please, please, please fix this Balpha or Marc! Or Rebecca? :-)

Comment: Also, @jball [see this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70790/graduated-sites-show-sketchy-offline-page/70801#70801)... :-)

Comment: @The Renamed Exception Well then. The typesetting mafia controls the world. :)

Comment: I guess technically, it is actually the *ugly url not being turned into a Onebox*, but that's all the more reason, as that means that it's 'known technology'.

Comment: +1. Note that these messages *do* get summary quasi-onebox text when they appear in the sidebar as the last message posted in another room you're in. I don't see why that same technology couldn't be applied here.