# Move starred onebox images to separate section in starred message list (aka StarScript)

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, onebox, chat-stars

We on Anime&Manga like images in chat, but we also like to still see relevant content in the starred chat message list. We just installed a chat bot that posts anime pictures from time to time and now our sidebar often looks like this:

[image]

I know, it's not cool to star trivial messages, but we can't do anything with our love for sweet girls. Which is why it would be for the best not to show oneboxed image links in the main starred message list, but instead move them to a separate mini-list made specifically for such messages (starred message list taken from DMZ chatroom):

[image]

Proposition: make a separate list of starred onebox images under the starred text message list, with thumbnails instead of just text links. Maybe even several rows. It should look something like this:

[image]

Other chat rooms will probably also love this feature.

---

**Update from 2020-07-02:** Increase the image size from 100px to 160px (native imgur image size) by adding this userstyle to your browser's favorite addon (I use Stylus for example):

```
#thumbs img {
    max-height: 160px !important;
    max-width: 160px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Updated version** from chat user Ascii-only: https://github.com/somebody1234/star-thumn

- Added a "lightbox" for viewing the images on left click without switching tabs
- Fixed a problem where the script does not load sometimes

---

So... **[I built this](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn)**!

It's a userscript, direct install link: **[Click Here](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn/raw/master/expando.user.js)** (Needs Greasemonkey on Firefox).

[image]

Comment: You should put this on http://stackapps.com/

Comment: [Done](http://stackapps.com/questions/6236/chat-starred-images-expander)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha remember i deleted my repo >_>