# Show bookmark name as the link text when link to one-boxed chat message is starred

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display onebox title in starred/pinned messages list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77803/display-onebox-title-in-starred-pinned-messages-list)

When posting a bookmark link in chat, it one-boxes the link, showing the name assigned to the bookmark:

[image: bookmark link posted in chat]

However, if that message is starred, it shows the link:

[image: starred chat message which is a one-boxed bookmark]

In the case of bookmarks, it would be *much* better if the link text was the name of the bookmark:

[image: mockup of link with link text equal to the bookmark title when starred]

It would be a nice touch instead of just a raw link so people at least have *some* idea of what they are clicking on.

It could even be prefixed with "Bookmark: " or something of that nature to indicate it's a bookmark.

Comment: I seem to remember the bookmark was called something else...

Comment: The feature bookmark or the actual bookmark referred to in the example.  If the former, I'm not sure, if the latter, I don't know what you're talking about (although I wish that were the case, honestly) =)