# Unexpected "Sketchy" themes on chat outage page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Similar (but not 100% related, linked Q is for Main Site):  [Graduated sites show "sketchy" offline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70790/graduated-sites-show-sketchy-offline-page).

Most recent chat outage is giving me a "Sketchy Beta" theme on most of the chat pages. This screenshot from "Chat.StackExchange":[image]

Also seen on the SuperUser room "Root Access". The StackOverflow chat was unaffected (by the theme change, not the outage).

Info: Windows 7 32-bit, IE8, ~18:30GMT

Comment: There's also the [related issue](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/689402#689402) of the page not appearing in an iframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have added custom offline pages and fixed the redirect for chat.