# Why has the Data Explorer the Beta Offline page?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, data-explorer

The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) does have the Beta-Offline page. Does it generally just lack it or was that an oversight?

[image: The Data offline page, showing the beta style.]

And I'm nearly 100% sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graduated sites show "sketchy" offline page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70790/graduated-sites-show-sketchy-offline-page)